# http error 404 for SOLR

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

Hello I am using SOLR (version 7.0.0) when start server , we got this error. How to fix it?

```
HTTP ERROR 404
```

Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

```
Not Found
```

Caused by:
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Have a look in the Solr log, it should have a more specific and useful error message about what's going wrong. That message can be a few things I believe, such as issues with core configuration, or errors in your Zookeeper setup.

Comment: Have a look in the Solr log, it should have a more specific and useful error message about what's going wrong. That message can be a few things I believe, such as issues with core configuration, or errors in your Zookeeper setup.

Comment: As @Jayce444 says - the real error message comes after that stacktrace you've pasted. Include the complete error message.

Comment: I am using centos 7. in SOLR path.. no logs folder. How to find it?

Comment: when i am use ./bin/solr status in command line appearFound 1 Solr nodes: 

Solr process 14474 running on port 8983

ERROR: Failed to get system information from http://10.10.0.101:8983/solr due to: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: Expected JSON response from server but received:

Answer (score 0):

We had the same error message presented within a Solr 8.11.2 instance (non-SOLR Cloud), and turns out the culprit was the 'security.json' file being malformed and containing an additional line break character.

We eventually found the issue whereby transforming using [Octostash](https://library.octopus.com/step-template/actiontemplate-variables-substitute-in-files) to substitute variables within the file before deploying via DevOps.

The solution in this case was to alter the original method with an alternative method discussed on this Reddit Thread ([click here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/v9md0u/comment/iby1k26/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3))

```
# Before
$EvaluatedTemplate | Out-File $TemplateFile -Force  -Encoding UTF8
# After
$EvaluatedTemplate -join "`r`n" | Set-Content $TemplateFile -NoNewLine
```

I hope this helps somebody out there,

Cheers